# change different color properies]

Tags: unity-game-engine

"Create a Sphere and add a collider on it from editor.
At the starting of your gameplay its collider should be disable by scripts.
Make a property like when we press ""SPACE"" button first time it color should be green.
On second press it color should be red.
On third press it color should be yellow.
On fourth press it scale increased upto 2.5
On fifth press its rotation should be changes to (0,90,0).
On sixth press its Collider should be destroyed.
and On nextpress at the place of sphere, Cube should be appers and its color same as sphere.
By pressing ""Y"" button cube scale should be reduced to 0.5.
if press ""A"" button then again cube disappper and sphere appers.
now if I press UpArrow then sphere moves forward and by DownArrow moves backward."

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone implement XY for me" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". Please make sure to take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).